# Resources on Fencing Numbers

Tags: geometry

Im currently working on a long term math project regarding fencing numbers, something like minesweepers but on a dot grid with connected lines instead of mines.

the original question can be found here
Fencing Numbers | AIMS Center Blog - AIMS Education Foundation
https://www.aimsedu.org/2014/05/12

does anyone know of extra resources for this question for us to cite as sources, or any good ways to expand on this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of providing a link only to your main page, and then having us try to find the appropriate page(s) for the original question, please provide a direct link to it instead. Thanks.

Comment: sorry the / was transferred incorrectly, i have corrected the link

Comment: Thanks for making the correction. I've read the article & find the concept interesting. There are, of course, several fairly obvious cases like any square with $4$ in it must have all sides used, and, thus, is a trivial case of a fence, plus for any $2$ adjacent squares where one is $3$ & the other is $0$ requires the $3$ one to use all sides other than the $0$ adjacent one, as shown in the article example. As for extra resources, the only thing I can think of is that it reminded me of graph theory, with the #'s being the # of connections, but no definitive theory for it. Good luck with it.

Comment: thank you very much, we will be using graph theory and 3d shapes to expand on the problem.